# File uploading issue in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am uploading an **.csv file** using below code and it works perfectly. But I am facing one issue during the upload. When I the choose the .csv for the first time, **submit button** will get enabled, but when I choose the wrong file instead of .csv, button is not getting disabled. If I want to clear the selected file the **clear button** is not working. I am not to figure it out what is wrong.

Below is the code of controller where upload file functionality take place:

Html:

```
<div class="col-md-2" >
        <input type="file" id="file1" name="file" ng-model="searchData" ng-files="getFiles($files)" multiple/>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2" style="padding:17px 0px 0px 55px">
  <button type="button" ng-click="uploadFile()" ng-disabled="!flag">SUBMIT</button>
  <button type="button" ng-click="clearFile()">CLEAR</button>
</div>
```

Angularjs:

```
var formData = new FormData();
    $scope.getFiles = function ($files) {
     var data = $files;
     if (data.length > 0) {
     formData.append('file1',data[0]);
     var allData = formData.get('file1');
     var filename = allData.name;  // Here we will get file name with type
        csvCheck = filename.substr(-4);   // Here I am selecting the last four char, i.e (.csv)
           if (csvCheck === ".csv") {
              $scope.flag = true;
           }
         } else {
            $scope.flag = false;
        }
        $timeout($scope.time(), 500); 
    };
```

[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/veGA35NM7vgPDSAJIsCw) is the plunker

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to accept only CSV files :

In your HTML Use :

```
<input type="file" id="file1" name="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().getFiles(this)" multiple/>
```

Then in your controller use:

```
$scope.getFiles = function ($files) {
var validExts = new Array(".csv");
var fileExt = $files.value;
fileExt = fileExt.substring(fileExt.lastIndexOf('.'));
if (validExts.indexOf(fileExt) < 0) {
  alert("Invalid file selected");
  $scope.flag=false;
}
else $scope.flag=true;
}
```

Use this code to clear the selected file :

```
document.getElementById("file1").value = "";
```

Comment: above logic is not working properly. Still I am facing the same issue. Alert mssg is displaying for the correct file also.